# How to use quotes correctly, when assembling a variable dynamically in jquery?

Tags: jquery, variables

I basically try to build a variable, which is dynamically changing:

The code looks as follows:

```
var test1 = $('.comfort-start');
    console.log(test1);


var pack = 'comfort' // in the real code, this is retrieved from another function
var test2 = $("'." + pack + "-start'");
    console.log(test2);
```

The first console.log

```
w.fn.init [div.comfort-start.main-categories.starter, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
```

The second one:

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   '.comfort-start'

I'm sure, I did that before and it worked. So what went wrong in this example?

Comment: Change `"'."` to just `"."`, and remove the single quote from the end part.  The actual string does not need quotes

Comment: Thanks. I also removed the end `"` in `var test2 = $("." + pack + "-start");` and it worked. I thought I tried everything. But what is the reason that the other quotes are not required?

Comment: Single or double quotes are javascript characters for denoting the start and stop of a string value.  But when parsed, they are not actually part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use simple quotes. ([Expression interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation))

```
var test2 = $("." + pack + "-start");
```

In **ES6** is called [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Uh, your answer is not using a template literal.  Edit: Also IE prior to Edge does not support template literals.

Comment: @Taplar I know. The link I posted has a section called "expression interpolation". I modified my answer to clarify the reference. Thanks.

Comment: My point is template literals use expression interpolation, but your answer does not include an example of it.  It just mentions it.  It would be more clear if you explained that the first version uses string concatenation, and then provide an example of the template literal and explain that it uses expression interpolation